# Vue3: how to reuse slot vnodes in a functional component

Tags: vue.js

Given this setup I can't figure how to keep the selection in the wrapped text input. When I set the text cursor in the middle, after typing the cursor jumps to the end due re-rendering.
I can fix it by setting

```
<input :key="1"/>
```

Obviously this option uses `creatElementBlock()`, with `key:1, patchFlag:0` as the result.

Unfortunately assigning this to the vnode doesn't help

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { ref, withDirectives, vModelText} from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello world...');

const wrapper = (props, {slots}) => {
  const out = slots.default();
  out.forEach(vnode => (vnode.key = 1) && Object.assign(vnode.props ??= {}, {
    'onUpdate:modelValue': text => props['onUpdate:modelValue'](text)
  }));
  return out.map(vnode => withDirectives(vnode, [[vModelText, props.modelValue]]));
};

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <wrapper v-model="msg">
    <input/>
  </wrapper>
</template>
```

Comment: "Obviously this option uses creatElementBlock(), with key:1, patchFlag:0" - this is likely the reason, the templates are compiled to optimized versions of render function. It looks like the problem is that you modify a vnode instead of creating a new one, this isn't documented usage.

Comment: @EstusFlask, agree, not documented... seems Vue collects blocks in a map for further processing or something like that. `createElementBlock` seems not pure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's good to play with [cloneVNode()](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#clonevnode) :

```js
const wrapper = (props, {slots}) => {
    const out = slots.default();
    
    const clonedVNodes = out.map(vnode => {
        const clonedVNode = cloneVNode(vnode, {
            'onUpdate:modelValue': text => props['onUpdate:modelValue'](text)
        });

        return withDirectives(clonedVNode, [[vModelText, props.modelValue]]);
    });

    return clonedVNodes;
};
```

[Full DEMO](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)